# aws s3 glacier restore from vault

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have vault and need to restore one of the folder from the vault I have initiated the job using AWS CLI and got the inventory using JSON file but unable to get the complete folder from the inventory. Any one can help me restoring the folder?
I am able to get CSV file formate to see the archive ID of the files but is it possible to take the complete folder as it is showing separate archive ID for all files in folder?

Comment: Amazon Glacier is _very_ difficult to use. I recommend finding a utility that understands how to use Glacier (eg Cyberduck, FastGlaicer, Cloudberry, Freeze) and use it to access the vault and archive.

Comment: can I use cloudberry for downloading folder from vault

Comment: Those tools can download 'archives', which are the files stored in a vault. There will be delays when requesting archives to be retrieved, but the tools can handle all that for you.